# Kafka not publishing file changes to topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Reading:[Kafka Connect FileStreamSource ignores appended lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374784/kafka-connect-filestreamsource-ignores-appended-lines)

An Answer from 2018 states :

```
Kafka Connect does not "watch" or "tail" a file. I don't believe it is documented anywhere that it does do that.
```

It seems Kafka does now support this as reading:

https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/managing/configuring.html#standalone-example

does state the file is watched:

> FileSource Connector The FileSource Connector reads data from a file
> and sends it to Apache Kafka®. Beyond the configurations common to all
> connectors it takes only an input file and output topic as properties.
> Here is an example configuration:
>
> name=local-file-source connector.class=FileStreamSource tasks.max=1
> file=/tmp/test.txt topic=connect-test This connector will read only
> one file and send the data within that file to Kafka. It will then
> watch the file for appended updates only. Any modification of file
> lines already sent to Kafka will not be reprocessed.

My configuration is same as question posted [Kafka Connect FileStreamSource ignores appended lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374784/kafka-connect-filestreamsource-ignores-appended-lines)

connect-file-source.properties contains:

```
name=my-file-connector
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/data/users/zamara/suivi_prod/app/data/logs.txt
topic=connect-test
```

Starting connect standalone with

```
connect-standalone connect-standalone.properties connect-file-source.properties
```

Adds all the contents of the file `logs.txt` to the topic `connect-test` , adding new lines to `logs.txt` does not add the lines to the topic. Is there configuration required to enable Kafka to watch the file so that new data added to `logs.txt` is added to the topic `connect-test` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're just experimenting with `FileStreamSource` for educational purposes, you're heading down a blind alley here. The connector only exists as a sample connector.

To ingest files into Kafka use Kafka Connect Spooldir, Kafka Connect FilePulse, or look at things like Filebeat from Elastic.

Comment: thanks for your answer. For now it's educational purposes, should FileStreamSource watch files by default or is there configuration required that I'm currently not utiilising? I will try something more robust as you suggest once I prove initial use case.